# random walk function in R

Tags: r, random-walk

I have a random walk function

```
random.walk = function(n){
  return(cunsum(c(0, sample(c(-1, 1), size = n-1, replace =TRUE))))
}
```

I would like to make recursive random walk function.
what I did was

```
recursive.rwalk=function(n){
  return(random.walk(n-1) + random.walk(n))
}
```

but then Im getting warning message. 
Please help me out!
Thanks

Comment: a warning message, huh? That's bad

Comment: What warning are you getting?  Note that in general, recursive functions are avoided in R.  R is not optimized to handle them ([see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273857/are-recursive-functions-used-in-r)).

Comment: what is `consum`? do you mean `cumsum`? `random.walk` takes an argument `k` and you do not use `k` in the function. Start there

Comment: a warning message : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: -1 "random walk function with recursive. solve the problem thank you" not a real question. I understand you've made an edit but until it gets remedied, -1.

Comment: bad question on SO.  rewrite question thank you.

Comment: What are you hoping the value of `recursive.rwalk(5)` be? For instance, do you want it to be a single value (the final position after a 5 unit walk), or a vector showing the route of the walk? Is the walk meant to be a walk of length 5 followed by a walk of length 4, or a walk of length 4 followed by a walk of length 1?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to add two vectors of different lengths: `n-1` and `n` in this line: `random.walk(n-1) + random.walk(n)`.  R is warning you that the first element of the first vector is added to the last element of the second vector (value recycling).

Answer (score 0):

Altough it's obviously not a good idea to calculate a random walk recursively in R, here is how you would do that. First of all you have to recursively call the `recursive.rwalk` function, not the `random.walk` function. Next, you still need to sample each step of the way. And finally you need to tell the function when to stop recursively calling itself. Here's one way that will work:

```
recursive.rwalk=function(n){
  if (n==0) return(0)
  rw <- recursive.rwalk(n-1)
  return(c(rw, rw[n-1]+sample(c(-1,1), 1)))
}
set.seed(123)
recursive.rwalk(5)
## [1] 0 1 0 1 2
```