# tibbletime - previous day's close

Tags: r, tibbletime

Please bear with me as this is my first question here. I'm still trying to figure out how to post the data and the code that I already have, so for now I will just try to explain. If this is not the acceptable way of asking a question, please ignore the question and next time I will try to do it right.

I have a data frame that I want to do daily calculations on. For a specific day I already have OpenUnits, BuyUnits, SellUnits, CloseUnits and Interest.These values were calculate by another system. I need to proportion the daily interest base on the number of units sold. I can do the calculations, but I cannot figure out how to get the OpenInterest (previous day's close), without using a for loop on the data frame. The ClosingInterest should be OpenInterest + Interest - SellUnits/OpenUnits * OpenInterest

I tried using mutate(OpenInterest = lag(ClosingInterest), ClosingInterest = OpenInterest + Interest - SellUnits/OpenUnits * OpenInterest), but that dosn't seem to work.

I have the code working with a for loop, but I was hoping that there might be a better, and faster way of doing it.

Regards

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tibbletime)
library(lubridate)

sample <- list(OpenUnits = c(7500000, 7500000, 7500000, 7500000, 7500000, 
                             3300000, 3300000, 3300000, 3300000, 3300000), ClosingUnits = c(7500000, 
                                                                                            7500000, 7500000, 7500000, 3300000, 3300000, 3300000, 3300000, 
                                                                                            3300000, 3300000), AccrualDate = 16892:16901, AiaAdjustAmt = c(1844.70359677349, 
                                                                                                                                                           1845.18465061665, 1845.66582990696, 1846.14713467713, 812.516568582349, 
                                                                                                                                                           812.728453146696, 812.940392965385, 813.152388052826, 813.364438423431, 
                                                                                                                                                           813.576544091616), SellUnits = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 4200000, NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                            NA, NA, NA, NA))
sample <- sample %>%
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(
    AccrualDate = lubridate::as_date(AccrualDate),
    SellUnits = if_else(is.na(SellUnits), 0, SellUnits)
  ) %>% 
  as_tbl_time(index = AccrualDate)

sample <- sample %>% 
  mutate(
    RealInterest = 0,
    OpenInterest = cumsum(AiaAdjustAmt) - cumsum(RealInterest) - AiaAdjustAmt - RealInterest,
    RealInterest = OpenInterest*SellUnits/OpenUnits 
  )
```

**This does not produce the correct answer.**

```
# A time tibble: 10 x 7
# Index: AccrualDate
   OpenUnits ClosingUnits AccrualDate AiaAdjustAmt SellUnits s24j_real s24j_open
       <dbl>        <dbl> <date>             <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1  7500000.     7500000. 2016-04-01         1845.        0.        0.        0.
 2  7500000.     7500000. 2016-04-02         1845.        0.        0.     1845.
 3  7500000.     7500000. 2016-04-03         1846.        0.        0.     3690.
 4  7500000.     7500000. 2016-04-04         1846.        0.        0.     5536.
 5  7500000.     3300000. 2016-04-05          813.  4200000.     4134.     7382.
 6  3300000.     3300000. 2016-04-06          813.        0.        0.     8194.
 7  3300000.     3300000. 2016-04-07          813.        0.        0.     9007.
 8  3300000.     3300000. 2016-04-08          813.        0.        0.     9820.
 9  3300000.     3300000. 2016-04-09          813.        0.        0.    10633.
10  3300000.     3300000. 2016-04-10          814.        0.        0.    11446.
```

The correct answer should look like this. This I achieved with a for loop, which I'm trying to avoid because it feels slow on the bigger data set that's also nested.

```
# A time tibble: 10 x 7
# Index: AccrualDate
   OpenUnits ClosingUnits AccrualDate AiaAdjustAmt SellUnits s24j_real s24j_open
       <dbl>        <dbl> <date>             <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1  7500000.     7500000. 2016-04-01         1845.        0.        0.        0.
 2  7500000.     7500000. 2016-04-02         1845.        0.        0.     1845.
 3  7500000.     7500000. 2016-04-03         1846.        0.        0.     3690.
 4  7500000.     7500000. 2016-04-04         1846.        0.        0.     5536.
 5  7500000.     3300000. 2016-04-05          813.  4200000.     4134.     7382.
 6  3300000.     3300000. 2016-04-06          813.        0.        0.     4060.
 7  3300000.     3300000. 2016-04-07          813.        0.        0.     4873.
 8  3300000.     3300000. 2016-04-08          813.        0.        0.     5686.
 9  3300000.     3300000. 2016-04-09          813.        0.        0.     6499.
10  3300000.     3300000. 2016-04-10          814.        0.        0.     7313.
```

Code to produce the correct answer.

```
sample2 <- sample %>% 
  mutate(
    sell_ratio = if_else(!is.na(SellUnits), SellUnits/OpenUnits, 0),
    s24j_open = 0,
    s24j_close = 0,
    s24j_real = 0     
  )

open <- 0
close <- 0  

for (i in seq_along(sample2$AccrualDate)) {

  open <- close
  sellratio <- sample2[i, ]$sell_ratio
  int <- sample2[i, ]$AiaAdjustAmt
  real <- sellratio*open

  close <- open - real + int

  sample2[i, ]$s24j_open <- open
  sample2[i, ]$s24j_real <- real
  sample2[i, ]$s24j_close <- close
}

sample2 %>% 
  select(
    OpenUnits, ClosingUnits, AccrualDate, AiaAdjustAmt, SellUnits, s24j_real, s24j_open
  )
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Add your code into the question (c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), as well as your data (reproducible example, or at least something like `head(data)`, `str(data)`). Also see here for help concerning formulating questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm working on a reproducible example. Will post soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better late than never:

```
## defining the data frame
sample <- data.frame(OpenUnits = c(7500000, 7500000, 7500000, 7500000, 7500000, 
                               3300000, 3300000, 3300000, 3300000, 3300000), 
                 ClosingUnits = c(7500000, 7500000, 7500000, 7500000, 3300000, 3300000, 3300000, 3300000, 3300000, 3300000), 
                 AccrualDate = 16892:16901, 
                 AiaAdjustAmt = c(1844.70359677349, 1845.18465061665, 1845.66582990696, 1846.14713467713, 812.516568582349, 
                                  812.728453146696, 812.940392965385, 813.152388052826, 813.364438423431, 813.576544091616), 
                 SellUnits = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 4200000, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))

## defining a function to deliver the final output
## warning: the function is recursive
myfct <- function(n){
  ratio <- (sample$SellUnits/sample$OpenUnits)[n]
  ratio <- ifelse(is.na(ratio), 0, ratio)
  if(n > 1){
    vec <- myfct(n-1)
    val <- vec[length(vec)]
    newval <- sample$AiaAdjustAmt[n]+val*(1-ratio)
    newvec <- c(vec, newval)
    return(newvec)
  }
  if(n == 1){return(sample$AiaAdjustAmt[n]+0*(1-ratio))}
}

## finally applying the function and binding the output
## depending on dim(sample)[1], here one might have to add something like:
## options(expressions=10000) (to avoid "Error: evaluation nested too deeply...")
close <- myfct(dim(sample)[1])
open <- c(0, close[1:(length(close)-1)])
real <- open*ifelse(is.na(sample$SellUnits/sample$OpenUnits),
                    0,
                    sample$SellUnits/sample$OpenUnits)
output <- cbind.data.frame(sample, real, open)
```

Here is the result:

```
> output
   OpenUnits ClosingUnits AccrualDate AiaAdjustAmt SellUnits     real     open
1    7500000      7500000       16892    1844.7036        NA    0.000    0.000
2    7500000      7500000       16893    1845.1847        NA    0.000 1844.704
3    7500000      7500000       16894    1845.6658        NA    0.000 3689.888
4    7500000      7500000       16895    1846.1471        NA    0.000 5535.554
5    7500000      3300000       16896     812.5166   4200000 4133.753 7381.701
6    3300000      3300000       16897     812.7285        NA    0.000 4060.465
7    3300000      3300000       16898     812.9404        NA    0.000 4873.194
8    3300000      3300000       16899     813.1524        NA    0.000 5686.134
9    3300000      3300000       16900     813.3644        NA    0.000 6499.286
10   3300000      3300000       16901     813.5765        NA    0.000 7312.651
```

**However**, recursive functions do not improve performance, quite the **opposite** ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273857/are-recursive-functions-used-in-r)). Although in the above code `myfct` is only applied to calculate `close` (`real` and `open` are derived from it). <s>At any rate, I believe the code could be modified in order to lose the recursiveness and/or `sapply` - I will give that a try and update the code then.</s>

**Edit**

The problem with the first version of my code was that using both a recursive function and sapply makes the process very lengthy. Indeed, `myfct(n)` already calulates `myfct(k)` for all `k<n`, thus using `sapply` to calculate these values was redundant and inefficient.

Here I left the old `function` and `sapply` for completeness (new `function` already edited in the above code):

```
myfct.old <- function(n){
  ratio <- (sample$SellUnits/sample$OpenUnits)[n]
  ratio <- ifelse(is.na(ratio), 0, ratio)
  if(n > 1){return(sample$AiaAdjustAmt[n]+myfct.old(n-1)*(1-ratio))}
  if(n == 1){return(sample$AiaAdjustAmt[n]+0*(1-ratio))}
}

## finally applying the function and binding the output
close <- sapply(1:dim(sample)[1], myfct)
```

Finally, here is a performance comparison of the different methods:

```
## Increasing the size of the data frame

sample <- do.call("rbind", replicate(100, sample, simplify = FALSE))

## (1) New method
start.time <- Sys.time()
close <- myfct(dim(sample)[1])
open <- c(0, close[1:(length(close)-1)])
real <- open*ifelse(is.na(sample$SellUnits/sample$OpenUnits),
                0,
                sample$SellUnits/sample$OpenUnits)
output <- cbind.data.frame(sample, real, open)
end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken1 <- end.time - start.time
time.taken1
"Time difference of 0.19402 secs"

## (2) A loop
start.time <- Sys.time()
close <- 0
s24j_open <- c()
s24j_real <- c()
s24j_close <- c()
for(k in 1:dim(sample)[1]){
  open <- close
  ratio <- (sample$SellUnits/sample$OpenUnits)[k]
  ratio <- ifelse(is.na(ratio), 0, ratio)
  real <- open*ratio
  close <- sample$AiaAdjustAmt[k]+open-real

  s24j_open <- c(s24j_open, open)
  s24j_real <- c(s24j_real, real)
  s24j_close <- c(s24j_close, close)
}
output <- cbind.data.frame(sample, s24j_real, s24j_open)
end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken2 <- end.time - start.time
time.taken2
"Time difference of 0.3530352 secs"

## (3) Old method
start.time <- Sys.time()
close <- sapply(1:dim(sample)[1], myfct.old)
open <- c(0, close[1:(length(close)-1)])
real <- open*ifelse(is.na(sample$SellUnits/sample$OpenUnits),
                    0,
                    sample$SellUnits/sample$OpenUnits)
output <- cbind.data.frame(sample, real, open)
end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken3 <- end.time - start.time
time.taken3
"Time difference of 48.86089 secs"
```

Comment: I tested your answer and can confirm that the recursive function is indeed significantly slower that the for loop, as you said it will be. Would be great if there are a solution that does not use a for loop or recursion. Thanks

Comment: @MartinduToit I believe to have found something helpful, c.f. the edit.

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks so much! On my full dataset of 60k rows, my original function took 114 seconds. Your solution takes 1.35 seconds. I must admit that I still need to figure out the logic, but for now I will settle for the speed improvement.

Comment: @MartinduToit Glad I could help! I had fun working on a solution. Feel free accept the answer :) (if my answer provides what you were looking for)

Comment: I'm new here :),  do I only have to tick the answer? It definitely provided me with what I was looking for.

Comment: @MartinduToit exactly, just ticking the answer suffices :)